# How do I start a launch agent for an AD user?

Tags: macos, launchd, launch-services

I have a Launch Agent which is working fine for local Mac users. But it is not starting for AD user. As we start a LaunchAgent using `launchctl bootstrap <gui/$user_uid> <plist path>`. But in the case of an AD user, we don't have the user_id beforehand. So when we switch users from a local user to an AD user my Launch Agent is not starting.
How do I start my Launch Agent for AD users?